# batchfile. Копирование каталога

Tags: cmd

Как с помощью `robocopy` скопировать папку с буквами "і,є" в названию?
Создал bat, сохранил в кодировке ОЕМ 866

```
set "sourcePath=d:\Іванє"
:: Define the destination folder.
set "destinationPath=G:\Іванє"
:: Use robocopy to copy the folder.
robocopy "!sourcePath!" "!destinationPath!" /E /MIR
```

Выдает ошибку

````
ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory D:\!sourcePath!\
The system cannot find the file specified.```
````

Comment: `!sourcePath!` не заменился на реальный путь. нужно дописать в батник какую-то строку, кажется, `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

Comment: ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory d:\▓трэ║\
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: вот, это уже настоящая ошибка!  попробуй поставь в первую строку батника `chcp 866`

Comment: ```ERROR : Invalid Parameter #1 : "d:\?ванє"```

Comment: первый символ в слове `Іванє` U+0406 отсутствует в [866](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866). Перепиши свой батник на 1251, там все твои буквы есть.